# Working on Radio Button value and text in jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the text of a radio button and set it as the text for . Also, I'd like to pass the value of the radio button in an ajax.

**Here is the template:**

```
   <div id="div_id_feature_selection" class="form-group">
        <label for="id_feature_selection_0" class=" requiredField">
              Feature selection<span class="asteriskField">*</span>
        </label>
        <div class="">
             <div class="form-check">
                 <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radio_selection" id="id_radio_selection_1" value="rdoSel1" >
                 <label for="id_radio_selection_1" class="form-check-label">
                      Radio Selection 1
                 </label>
             </div>

             <div class="form-check">
                 <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radio_selection" id="id_radio_selection_2" value="rdoSel2" >
                 <label for="id_radio_selection_2" class="form-check-label">
                      Radio Selection 2
                 </label>
             </div>

             <div class="form-check">
                 <input type="radio" class="form-check-input" name="radio_selection" id="id_radio_selection_3" value="rdoSel3" >
                 <label for="id_radio_selection_3" class="form-check-label">
                      Radio Selection 3
                 </label>
             </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

This is where the selected radio button text should be copied to

```
   <h6 id="rdo_text_copy">None </h6>
```

An ajax call to pass the selected radio button's value

```
    $("input[type='radio]").click(function(){
        var rdo_option = $("input[name='radio_selection']:checked").val(),
            rdo_option_name = $("input[name='radio_selection']:checked").text();
        if(rdo_option){
            sel_option=rdo_option;
            $("#rdo_text_copy").text(rdo_option_name);
        }
    });

    $("#btnSelect").click(function(){
        ...
        $.ajax({
            ...
            data: {
                ...
                sel_option_value: sel_option,

            },
            success: function(response){
                ...
            }
        });
    });
```

I tried to put the following code at the top but only the first radio button's value is retrieved.
Without this line at the top, the click event is not working.

```
   sel_technique = $("input[name='feature_selection']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you mentioned you are trying to use code that references `feature_selection` but that doesn't exist in your HTML.

Instead of messing with `text` of the radio you can use `next` to get the label after the `radio` since that is the pattern of your HTML.

```
$("input[name='radio_selection']").change(function(){
    $("#rdo_text_copy").text($("input[name='radio_selection']:checked").next("label").text());
});
```